# Can jQuery execute sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/c4zquo60/1/

CSS:

```
#bg {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    width:100wh;
    height:100vh;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#triggerModel').hover(function () {
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
        $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('backgroundModel.jpg')"});
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#triggerArt').hover(function () {
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
        $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('backgroundArt.jpg')"});
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#triggerDev').hover(function () {
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
        $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('backgroundDev.jpg')"});
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
    });
});
```

And my limited understanding of programming is that the compiler SHOULD execute each line sequentially. For example, shouldn't it read `$("#bg").css({'opacity':0});`, know to put the opacity to 0, THEN read `$("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('backgroundModel.jpg')"});` to switch the background image, and then the third line to make opacity 1 again?

When the page loads, per the CSS code, the background image has an opacity of 0 and no image loaded. When I hover over the element, it properly animates. But when I hover over another (of 3) nav elements, it ignores the opacity easing, and just switches straight away to the next background image.

Is there a way to force jQuery to execute the instructions sequentially? Do I need to set a delay between each function to wait for the transition perhaps? Or is jQuery simply not recognizing the transition in the CSS code after the first execution?

Comment: It does run sequentially, but the browser does not redraw for each change.  It must be given a chance to do so.  Quick running javascript can do many DOM changes before a redraw actually takes place.  It would be *very* inefficient if the browser redrew for every change.

Comment: The css updates are happening so fast that you won't see the changes. If you want easing you will need to do it with some type of animation whether css or jquery

Comment: just a heads up, your code is a bit redundant -- you do not need to wrap every `$('#triggerDev')...` into another `$(function(){ .... })` block

Comment: @Jhecht Thank you! I'm really new to jQuery, so far I've been struggling to read and understand how to implement valid code, much less make it pretty. I've fixed the code in my directory per your suggestion

Comment: @Taplar would the inefficiency make the webpage unusable if this was the only script on the page? I don't plan on including much more on this landing page, I'm trying to keep it simple. That being said, is it worth pursuing a solution to complete the code I've already written above? Or should I just scrap it and approach it through another, more efficient method?

Comment: Please don't miss understand the point I was trying to make.  There's nothing wrong with you making scripts that intentionally delay things before other things happen.  The inefficiency I was talking about was if the browser redrew for every change that happened to the DOM by default, *that* would be a big inefficiency.  @TonyWhite

Comment: @Taplar I think I understand, so for future reference if I need to put in delays, I need to remember to explicitly do this because the DOM won't by design, correct? Thank you for the advice by the way. I'm new and so things that should be obvious, I've still got to learn ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to account for the delay you specified in your css.
as JS/jQuery doesn't know about it.

That said, you can use mouseover() and mouseout() to get it working better

```
$(function() {
    $('#triggerModel').mouseover(function () {
           $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
           $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('https://i.imgur.com/QZ5H6bo.jpg')"});
    }).mouseout(function(){
           $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
    });


    $('#triggerArt').mouseover(function () {
           $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
           $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('https://i.imgur.com/tS8WsBm.jpg')"});
    }).mouseout(function(){
             $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
    });

    $('#triggerDev').hover(function () {
           $("#bg").css({'opacity':1});
       $("#bg").css({'background-image': "url('https://i.imgur.com/b4V9l6u.jpg')"});
    }).mouseout(function(){
             $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
    });

});
```

Here https://jsfiddle.net/mw3v49vt/
thats closer to what you want i assume

**EDIT:**

Changes to the HTML/DOM:
Notice that i removed the **id** and changed it for a **class**
then i added the tag **data-bgimg** which contains the link to the background img.
that way when you want to add a similar effect somewhere
all you have to do is change the **data-bgimg** url

```
<div class="interactiveBackground" data-bgimg="https://i.imgur.com/b4V9l6u.jpg" style="float:right;">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/VrVx9iQ.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Reusable JS code: 
we point to the class *interactiveBackground* and then
use *$(this)* which refers the DOM object that has the *interactiveBackground*
we just triggered. and target its *data-bgimg* attribute and read it into
the *background* variable.

```
$(function() {

  $('.interactiveBackground').mouseover(function(){
        var background = $(this).attr('data-bgimg');
        $('#bg').css({'opacity':1});
        $("#bg").css({'background-image':"url('" + background + "')" });
  }).mouseout(function(){
        $("#bg").css({'opacity':0});
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/02en3973/

Comment: That seems to work perfect for me. Is there a reason the third trigger is still `.hover()`?

Comment: no just a mistake. in a quick effort to give you something useful.
but i suppose that works as well.

Although what i provided isn't the best solution. 
To elaborate,  currently it triggers an effect when the mouse enters one of the blocks and another effect when it leaves.